# Find the vector by the following criteria

Tags: analytic-geometry

I want to find the vector that meets the following:
$$X\parallel (2,1,-1)$$
$$X*(2,1,-1)=3$$
what I did so far is :
$$2x+y+z=3$$
I know that parallel vectors the angle is $180$ or $0$.

how to continue from here?

Note: X is vector.
Thanks!

Comment: What $X * (2,1,-1)$ does mean?

Comment: @dtldarek: presumably, inner product

Comment: I'd suggest taking another look at that $2x+y+z=3$ thing. Then I'd interpret parallelism as "is a constant multiple of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to notice that $X\parallel Y$ iff $X = a Y$  for some $a\in \Bbb R$. That is, you know that 
$$
  X = (2a,a,-a)
$$
and that $2a\cdot 2 + a\cdot 1+(-a)\cdot (-1) = 3$ which will give you $a$.

An "alternative" way which is not really an alternative is so mention that you have two conditions: $X\parallel Y$ and $X\cdot Y = 3$. The first is equivalent to $X = aY$ as we already discussed, so the second now turns to be
$$
  3 = X\cdot Y = aY\cdot Y = a\|Y\|^2 \iff a = \frac3{\|Y\|^2}
$$
where $\|Y\|$ is the length of $Y$, which you can find using squares and square roots.

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.

Comment: Ok, so for example I have$$ X\parallel (2,1,-1)$$ and the second thing is $$|X|=3 $$ is mean that is going to be $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ than I insert the X as you did?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: indeed, but I'm pretty sure that OP has more than this single problem on the same topic, so I saw no harm of showing how would it work till the end.

Comment: @OfirAttia: indeed. Note, however, that in problem you came up with it holds that $|aY| = |-aY|$, so that you'll have two solutions.

Comment: @Ilya I think you want the denominator of your final fraction to be $\|Y\|^2$ and not $\|Y^2\|$.

Comment: yes, I understand that, thanks!

Comment: @Daryl: fixed, thanks